# windows server 2008 r2 self signed certificate sha256

Tags: certificate, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2, sha

I need a self signed certificate for a site in the intranet, but the server runs windows server 2008 r2 when i create a self signed certificate in IIS (7.5) it is created with the SHA1RSA algorithm but when users try to go to the intranet site (https://) gives the error `ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH` i understand that is because the brower is not compatible for the SHA1 algorithm, so i need to create a self signed certificate but using the SHA256 algorithm, is this possible on Windows Server 2008 R2? how can I do it?

Thanks in advance for any clue or suggestion

Comment: https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/self-signed.html

Comment: When I try to open Jexus Manager never opens so I check the event viewer and shows me this: 
Description: A .NET application failed.
Application: JexusManager.exe
Path: C:\Program Files\Jexus Manager\JexusManager.exe
Message: Failed to load the dll from [C:\Program Files\Jexus Manager\hostfxr.dll], HRESULT: 0x80070057
The library hostfxr.dll was found, but loading it from C:\Program Files\Jexus Manager\hostfxr.dll failed
  - Installing .NET prerequisites might help resolve this problem.
     https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=798306

Comment: As you are using a deprecated Windows release, the latest Jexus Manager might break (as it relies on latest .NET runtime). You might try an old release like 13.0.0.x, https://github.com/jexuswebserver/JexusManager/releases/tag/v13.0.0.20

Comment: the link is down :(

Comment: You might try https://github.com/jexuswebserver/JexusManager/releases/tag/v13.0.0.27 or https://github.com/jexuswebserver/JexusManager/releases/tag/v12.0.95.0.

Comment: finally i can run jexus and create the certificate with SHA256RSA but still don't work, i think win server 2008 r2 can't host https sites for the new web browser

Comment: Run a report to learn what's wrong, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ssl-diagnostics.html But you cannot ask too much from a deprecated Windows release either. Modern web needs a modern Windows release.

Answer (score 1):

By Default, if you generate the Self-Signed Certificate from the IIS Manager Console it will provide a Self-Signed Certificate with the Signature hash algorithm as sha1 .

The SHA-1 hashing algorithm for the Microsoft Root Certificate Program is being decommissioned.

If you want your self-signed certificate should use the sha256 Signature hash algorithm, you have to generate the certificate from the mmc console.

You can follow the steps in the document below to create and use a self-signed certificate with a signature hash algorithm of sha256.

[SHA-256 Self Signed Certificate for Windows Server 2012 R2](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/archive/blogs/mayurpatankar/sha-256-self-signed-certificate-for-windows-server-2012-r2)

I don't have a Windows Server 2008 r2 system, so not sure if this will work on Windows Server 2008 R2, but you might as well give it a try, hope it helps.

Comment: I tried but is not the same and after step 10 it's confusing

Comment: Does this link work for you? https://support.jetglobal.com/hc/en-us/articles/235636308-How-To-Create-a-SHA-256-Self-Signed-Certificate

Comment: the powershell from windows server 2008 r2 don't support that functions